# Android - How to chain multiple asynchronous methods in a readable manner

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

On app startup I would like to check multiple conditions like so:

```java
onCreate() {
    result1 = method1();
    result2 = method2(result1);
    result3 = method3(result2);
}
```

Now these methods depend on user input or network requests so they can't be called like that. Instead, I had to have a layout like this:

```java
onCreate() {
    method1();
}
method1() {
    doStuff();
    somekindOfCallbackThatStuffIsDone(result1) {
        method2(result1);
    };
}
method2(result1) {
    doStuff(result1);
    somekindOfCallbackThatStuffIsDone(result1) {
        method3(result2);
    }
}
```

Now this still looks kind of okay in the example, but it turned out super messy in code, because there are five of these with multiple conditions on each one. Is there a way for the code to be as easily readible as in the first box?

Comment: If there's user interaction involved to execute methodN+1, you're doing it correct. Otherwise, you need to take a look into Kotlin Coroutines.

Comment: This is right. It is called "Callback hell"

Comment: Oh no. Thank you for your responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @Phantom Lord this is known as **Callback hell** and a possible solution in the absence of user interaction are **Kotlin Coroutines** according to @theapache64.